# Thread-Safe Clearing of CopyOnWriteArrayList After Processing

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, copyonwritearraylist

I have a Java program using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that is being iterated through by an `update()` method in a thread that runs on a certain time interval and that processes each item in the list. The items in the list are not thread-safe, so I'm processing modifications to the items using various `CopyOnWriteArrayList` buffers that are used to know which items to modify  and how when the `update()` method iterates through the list.

The issue is that once I've used those buffers, I `clear()` them, but am afraid that an item may have been added to the buffer between when the buffer is used and when it's cleared.

**For example:**

```
mainList.addAll(bufferAddList);
bufferAddList.clear();
```

**Example 2:**

```
for (Item item : mainList) { // Main iterator loop
    if (bufferModItemList.contains(item)) {
        item.modify();
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
bufferModItemList.clear();
```

I'm afraid that using `synchronize` around the code blocks that read/modify those lists would cause the main thread to lock up (which where calls to modifications would come from), because the processing that happens during iteration through the items takes a while (Python scripts are called and waited on). That's why I'm using the buffers in the first place.

Is there a better way to do this than either of the ways I've mentioned?

Note that both examples show code that would run in the `update()` method, which is in the thread's "infinite" while loop.

**UPDATE**

It appears that using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` will satisfy the issue with Example 2. However, it seems as though using it for the first example would be overkill, since I essentially just want to add all the nodes to the `mainList`. It would be great if `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` had a `.pollAll()` method!

Also, for the following example, I'd have to iteratively remove items from `mainList`, which I don't want to do since it's a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Although I'm not sure it needs to be one any more...

**Example 3:**

```
mainList.removeAll(bufferRemoveList);
bufferRemoveList.clear();
```

Comment: If you're clearing the list after processing, perhaps you should be using a Queue instead?

Comment: @dnault Thanks! It looks like ConcurrentLinkedQueue will satisfy my needs for Example 2.

Comment: It seems to me that the present behaviour is exactly what you really want. You only want to remove the items that you've processed. You don't want to lose other items that have been added by other threads while you were processing.